# SQL Can't convert to time format computed ss to HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't convert to computed ss to hh:mm:ss to time even though it is formatted as time.This is the query I have. Is there a work around here?

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(263827 / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' + 
       RIGHT('0' + CAST((263827 / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' + 
       RIGHT('0' + CAST(263827 % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  [Released]
```

I tried using `CONVERT(time, DATEADD(ms, SUM(aa.Released) * 1000, 0))` but does not return the correct output.

Edit 1: Current output is `73:17:07` but I cant convert it to time format when I use the `CONVERT` function the error says

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Comment: Your question doesn’t make much sense sorry. Post some example data from your tables and the result output you want for each data

Comment: Kindly share the desired output

Comment: @CaiusJard the data is included on the question. But I will update the question to post the expected output

Comment: Do you want to convert integer to time?

Comment: What you tried to calculate is not **time** in the terms of `time` data type. It is **duration**. `time` data type can store values smaller than 24h, while your result can easily get bigger. You can't convert it to `time`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I was going to turn 263827 into hours minutes and seconds, I’d use dateadd

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(SECOND, 263827, '1970-01-01'), 'HH:mm:ss')
```

Pre 2012 versions of sqlserver don’t have format:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(SECOND, 263827, '1970-01-01'), 8)
```

Theres no particular reason I chose 1st jan 1970, any date with a time of midnight would work, but this date is the unix epoch so as a technique it can be used for turning unix time (INT64 number of seconds since jan 1, 1970) into a usable DATETIME..

Note that this approach doesn’t work for seconds over 86400 because it is limited to 24 hours before it rolls over to the next day. You could FORMAT to add "day of year" if you wanted e.g. up to "365d 23:59:59" of duration.

To turn a number of seconds into hundreds of hours, do it mathematically:

```
SELECT CONCAT(263827/3600, FORMAT(DATEADD(SECOND, 263827, '1970-01-01'), ':mm:ss'))
```

This is the simplest (shortest code) way I can think of without getting into lots of divide and mod operations (messy)

Comment: the returned value for these is `01:17:07` it does not captured the 3 days or `72 hours` output should be `73:17:07` if possible

Comment: Added a note to address that

Answer (score 1):

The upper limit of time datatype is `23:59:59`, you can convert any `varchar` to `time` if it equal or below `23:59:59`.

In your case `73:17:07` is beyond the limit of `time` datatype so you will get the casting error.